# Paying with options besides PayPal

Tags: cognito-forms

If people do not wish to pay by PayPal (e.g., they are going to EFT the money) is there are way they can submit the form without having to press the "Check out with PayPal" button.  They are all becoming confused about not having an ordinary submit button.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

You can set up a Choice field that ask the user if they will be paying via PayPal or via other options, you can then have the Payment section at the bottom of your form to be required based on the users selection in the Choice field.

You can learn more about setting this up in our [Collecting Payments Nor or Later Blog post](http://blog.cognitoforms.com/collect-payments-now-or-later-with-cognito-forms).